# Where to commission 3D models?

Tags: modeling

I'm a fairly practiced 3D modeler, but I can never get my creations to even look remotely close to how I imagine them. I'm creating some jewelry as a gift so not only does it have to be precise, but it has to be quick because Christmas is coming up fast and I still have to print and cast it.

Where should I look to commission a 3D model? Referrals, websites, or personal volunteers? Does anyone have an recommendations of safe legit payment systems or websites (if it's even worth paying for)?

Comment: This is probably the wrong place to ask this, but it's close enough. The rules on this site are alright and make sesne, but many take them too far and do everything in thier power to correct and/or punish you. If I can only ask certain questions, how does that help me? If I cannot give additional information in an answer, then there will just be more unanswered questions. The Blender SE is alright, but when you start getting into more controversial territory, it's always one sided and if you don't have the "right" answer, you won't last long.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to model this object? Or will someone do it for you?

Comment: @Timaroberts Who can do it and/or where can I ask?

Comment: Any information related to commissions would be helpful, really.

Comment: Blenderartists.org has a "Paid Work" forum. You could try there.

Comment: @Danial Alright, I'll try there.

Comment: B.SE is dedicated to questions about using blender itself. For requesting/commissioning work, you might check out [blenderartists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?52-Paid-Work) (as mentioned above), or [blendswap](http://www.blendswap.com/page/request-blends)

Comment: @gandalf3 No, it is not a job offer/model request. I'm asking for information about commissioning and personal references if applicable.  I quote "...Though, I ran into a problem; I don't know where to look." ... "Referrals, websites, volunteers (of course I would not refuse any help), suggestions on safe and legit payment." ... Timaroberts: "what exactly  is your question?" Me: "Who can do it and/or where can I ask".

Comment: @JosiahPanak Well, since this sort of thing has been asked a couple times in the past, I could see this question being a very useful general reference. With this in mind, 10Replies and I have edited your question to remove details about your specific request.

Comment: https://www.blendernetwork.org/ is a good place to start looking. Many of the artists there are open to freelance work, I'm not sure if there is a place to list freelance jobs though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question specifically about the Blender software